# Join table on one of the row

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I have a table, say, Person with fields

```
id  name
1    Jone
2    Jane
```

Got another table address

```
id   person_id   address_type
1    1           Permanent
2    1           Temporary
```

I want to select table Person to Address such that if a person has Temporary address then join it else join with Parmanent address.

I can do:

```
    select * 
    from person p 
    left join address at on at.person_id=p.id and at.type='Temporary' 
    left join address al on al.person_id=p.id and at.type='Permanent'
```

But joining address table twice seems like overkill here. Can I just join address only once such that I get:

```
-> If Temporary is there, join with Temporary
-> If temporary is not there, join with permanent
-> If pernamenet is not there join address with all null fields.
```

Help?

Comment: Join address table by something like `on at.person_id=p.id and at.type=MAX(at.type) OVER (PARTITION BY at.person_id)`.

Comment: Do you have three types, Permanent, Temporary and Local ?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille typo.

Comment: It happens to the best.

Answer (score 3):

This could be done using a left join to a derived table that picks the correct address:

```
select p.*, a.id as address_id, a.address_type
from person p
  left join (
     select ad.*, 
            row_number() over (partition by ad.person_id 
                               order by case when ad.address_type = 'Temporary' then 1 else 2 end) as rn
     from address ad
  ) a on a.person_id = p.id and a.rn = 1;
```

The case expression for the `order by` inside the window function could also be written as `decode(ad.address_type, 'Permanent', 1, 2)`, but I prefer standard SQL over Oracle specific one if both are equivalent.

---

Another option - that might or might not be faster - is to use a lateral join with a `fetch first` clause.

```
select p.*, a.id as address_id, a.address_type
from person p
  left join lateral (
     select *
     from address ad
     where ad.person_id = p.id
     order by case when ad.address_type = 'Temporary' then 1 else 2 end
     fetch first 1 rows only
  ) a on 1 = 1;
```

The lateral left join returns one row for each person_id from the outer query (because of the `fetch first 1 rows only`)